# Jenkinsfile using parameters for image prefix

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to use a parameter in my Jenkinsfile for my containerTemplate image prefix?

I'm working in disconnected environment and use a proxy to access my images.  If a developer has a Jenkinsfile they wish to deploy to my environment, they'll need to specify the image prefixes to use my proxy in their podTemplate.  It's conceivable they could be deploying their application to multiple environments where the image prefix would change.  Seems like overkill to ask a contributor to maintain multiple sets of Jenkinsfiles suitable for deployments in differing environments. I've tried setting a string parameter in my build setup but that appears to only be used in the build and not the containerTemplate definition.

Here is a Jenkinsfile example of what I am trying to accomplish.  I'd like to be able to pass in the value for ${repo_url}:

```
  containerTemplate(name: 'min', image: '${repo_url}/rhel7-minimal', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true)
]) {
    node('label') {
       stage('Hello World') {
         container('min') {
           echo "HELLO WORLD"
         }
       } 
    }
}
```

Comment: use " " instead of ' ' for GString variable substitution. -> image: "${repo_url}/rhel7-minimal"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you configure [configure your pipeline to accept parameters](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build), you can access them with [${params.parameter}](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-parameters)

Comment: I tried that by choosing 'This project is parameterized' and creating a repo_url string parameter, but trying to access in my container image name as: image: '${params.repo_url}/rhel7-minimal' fails as it is not using the variable value, but rather it is trying to pull the image tag: ${params.repo_url}/rhel7-minimal

Comment: Needed double quotes around the image name.